# How can I change a file name on Amazon S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have an application that uploads files to `Amazon S3` but right now I have the requirement to add a new feature to rename a file in an `S3` Bucket.

I would like to know how to rename a file that is already uploaded to `Amazon S3`?

Comment: I'm no Amazon expert, but on Azure you have to copy with a new name and delete the old.

Comment: Yes sounds to be similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rename for amazon s3 object but as work around you can Copy the object with a new name then Delete the old one.

Comment: How much time it would take to copy and paste it in the same bucket and at same location.My file size(compressed xml file) is approx. 2-3 GB , so I am concerned about it

Comment: Please review my new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880500/how-can-i-change-a-file-name-on-amazon-s3/58768001#58768001). It seems copy object is more efficient way instead of download+upload way.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement renaming using two operations:

1. [CopyObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_CopyObjectRequest.htm)
2. [DeleteObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TDeleteObjectRequest.html)

Also please review this [link](http://arkleseizure.net/bulk-renaming-files-in-amazon-s3) for more details (and code examples).